# Is grep showing wrong row number?

Tags: r, dataframe

I can only explain this by posting a picture. `grep()` returns the rows where "DE" appears but shifted 31 spots down. Why?

[image]

Comment: not reproducible, since data is provided in [.NORM](https://xkcd.com/2116/)-format.

Comment: what is the value of row 201?

Comment: If you delete rows in a dataframe the row numbers remain the same as they were before deletion, grep gives you the row index. In this case I am quite sure that grep is right and your dataframe's row numbering is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My **guess** (but really just that given that you haven't posted any reproducible data) is that you've removed some rows previously (see e.g. the fact that row `235` is followed by row `237`) and you are mistaking *indices* for *row numbers*.

For example:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = 1:8,
  geo = c("AU", "AU", "DE", "DE", "CZ", "CZ", "DE", "BE")
)
```

If you remove some rows, like so:

```
df <- df[-which(grepl("AU", df$geo)),]
df
  id geo
3  3  DE
4  4  DE
5  5  CZ
6  6  CZ
7  7  DE
8  8  BE
```

and now use `grep`, you get:

```
grep("DE", df$geo)
[1] 1 2 5
```

This is because `grep`does not show row numbers; it shows indices. In the edited `df`, the `DE` value has index `1, 2, 5`.

If you want the **row numbers**, you can use the `dplyr` function  `row_number()`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(row_n = row_number()) %>%
  filter(grepl("DE", geo))            # NB: works only with *grepl* not *grep*
  id geo row_n
1  3  DE     1
2  4  DE     2
3  7  DE     5
```

Comment: I have removed rows previously yes. I have used grep() and then removed the rows returned by grep. Does this mean I have removed all the wrong rows?!

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann:  I think you should say "row labels" instead of "row numbers".  I think of "indices" and "row numbers" as the same thing.

Comment: I see, row indices are not actually used for matrix / Dataframe operations, rownumbers are. So when I use grep() and get rownumbers and create a new dataframe
df <-- df[,-c(grep(...) ) I do remove exactly what I want